# $facebook->api('/me') returning blank from today morning

Tags: facebook

My facebook application was working fine yesterday but from today morning, I am getting below error:
CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 66.220.147.38: No buffer space

I also see many updates on facebook itself from today morning. Any idea why is this happening?

Prompt response would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

api('/me') is known to have a problematic history.. try using api('/< FB_APPLICATION_ID >

Comment: I tried using api('/my_application_id') but it's still giving me same problem.

Comment: type https//graph.facebook.com/< app_id > on the browser and see if correct data is being returned .. if it returns false you are using a wrong id

Comment: I get below error Unable to download in IE but in mozlilla I am getting: when I give below:
"id": "148819121847983",
   "name": "New Application",
   "link": "applink",
   "canvas_name": "canvasname",
   "icon_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yT/r/4QVMqOjUhcd.gif",
   "logo_url": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yq/r/IobSBNz4FuT.gif"

 https://graph.facebook.com/148819121847983

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a client side problem on your side, an error from Facebook would generally return an error message or exception

it sounds like your curl instance can't contact Facebook's servers (or allocate the memory or port needed to make the connection) - have you reached your max outgoing connections or some other TCP/IP restriction in your server configuration?